# Show that $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \mathbb{R}}$, $f_\alpha = p(\alpha)$ is linearly independent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials, real-numbers

I think this one mights be a very known (or even simple) result but I simply don't know how to Google it or what issues to search for in a book. So, what do you guys recommend (duplicate or even some link of the proof, suggestion of books, anything) to the following (it's an exercise in Linear Algebra that I couldn't do at all):

Consider $V=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Given $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ let $f_\alpha \in V^*$ be the linear functional defined by
$$f_\alpha:\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$p(x) \mapsto p(\alpha)$$
Show that $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent set in $V^*$.

What I have tried: Consider $a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in \mathbb{R}$ distincts. Let's show that if $$\tag{1}\sum_{i=1}^na_if_{\alpha_i}=\mathscr{O}\in V^*\text{(the zero linear functional)}$$
then $a_i=0,\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. If (1) holds, then, for all $p(x)\in V$ we have
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_if_{\alpha_i}\right)(p(x))=0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^na_ip(\alpha_i)=0. \tag{2}$$
Then, my idea was to choose some suitable polynomials and conclude, maybe by a system, that $a_i=0$. I've chosen $p_k(x)=x^k,k\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and was led to the system
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&1&\dots&1\\
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \dots & \alpha_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\alpha_1^{n-1} & \alpha_2^{n-1}&\dots & \alpha_n^{n-1} \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} a_1\\ a_2\\ \vdots \\a_n \end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\ \vdots \\0\end{array}\right)$$
but from here to conclude that $a_i=0$ is not clear to me (I don't know anything about the $\alpha_i$'s!)

Maybe other choice of the $p_k(x)$ or even a completely different way of solving this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: This may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix In particular, since the $\alpha_i$ are distinct, the square matrix in your system is invertible.

Comment: Can I prove, for instance, that this matrix of $\alpha_i^k$'s is invertible?

Comment: Thanks! @Travis! I'll check it out

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336408/303887

Comment: Thank you @RafaelHolanda! I'll see if I can prove that this matrix is invertible by induction ;)

Comment: Assuming $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_{k}f_{\alpha_{k}}=0$ for some constants $\beta_k$, evaluate at a polynomial $p$ that is $0$ at every $\alpha_k$ except for one of them where it is $1$. Conclude that each constant $\beta_{k}$ in turn is $0$.

Comment: That's right  @TrialAndError, thank you very much. A very simple way of solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have $f_{\alpha_k}$ and $\beta_k$ such that
$f=\sum_k \beta_k f_{\alpha_k} = 0$.

Let $p_k (x) = { \prod_{i \neq k} (x-\alpha_i) \over \prod_{i \neq k} (\alpha_k-\alpha_i)} $ and note that $p_k(\alpha_i) = \delta_{ik}$.

Then $f(p_k) = \beta_k = 0$ and so $\beta_k = 0$.

Comment: Yes, yes. A very simpler way of solving the problem. A friend of mine told me this one last night and, of course, it's correct. (Albeit that one cited above isn't wrong) @copper.hat